# How to dynamically add static resources to spring-boot jar application?

Tags: java, spring, jar, resources, spring-boot

I have spring-boot application which creates catalog with html static pages. When I start application by command: `mvn spring-boot:run` everything works good (folder with static pages is created in `/resources/` catalog and client have access to pages) but I want have my app deployed as jar file and here I have my question, how can I achieve my goal? I understand that I can't add dynamically resources to jar but maybe I can create folder with resources next to my jar file and somehow add this folder to public resources so client could have access to html pages.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: I tried add /path/to/folder/ to static content by extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter but it didn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try prefixing you resource location with `file:`, for example:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/external/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:external/");
}
```

This path is relative to the directory from which you launched the application. You can also use an absolute path, for example `file:/path/to/resources`.