# Spring Boot 1.1.9+ addResourceHandler not working for static assets for absolute paths

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with static html, css, and img files we want to keep outside of the /static directory (during development) for purposes of modularity and easy reloading and developing.   It is our front end component written in AngularJS.   Problem is in 1.1.8, the following registration worked:

```
String userDir = System.getProperties().getProperty("user.dir");
String prefix = "file:";

registry.addResourceHandler("/diagnostics/systemstatusng/**").addResourceLocations(prefix + userDir + "/myAngularFrontend1/app/**");
registry.addResourceHandler("/loginondemand/**").addResourceLocations(prefix + userDir + "/myAngularFrontEnd2/app/**");
```

But in spring-boot-starter 1.1.9 (and 1.2.0.RC1), this no longer works.

Looking at this recent post [How to dynamically add static resources to spring-boot jar application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871131/how-to-dynamically-add-static-resources-to-spring-boot-jar-application), seems like it should work, but we've tried left and right and cant figure out why it doesnt work in spring boot starter 1.1.9 and later.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource locations need to be directories (not patterns) ending in "/", e.g.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/diagnostics/systemstatusng/**").addResourceLocations(prefix + userDir + "/myAngularFrontend1/app/");
```

Nothing changed in Spring Boot (this is a core Spring MVC feature), so you must have just been doing it differently before.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  That was it.   Interesting that we narrowed down the behavioral difference to spring-webmvc.jar.  The 4.0.7 version tolerated that ** on the directory name whereas 4.0.8 and beyond did not.